# elastic search matching document against all other documents

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say the scheme is something like:

```json
{
   title: string
   description: string,
   tags: [string],
   categories: [string]
}
```

Now let's say that instead of a `search query` I want to match a single document against all others and find the best matching ones. I want it to search `title` against `title`, `description` against `description` etc. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the [More Like this Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) can help

> The More Like This Query finds documents that are "like" a given set
> of documents. In order to do so, MLT selects a set of representative
> terms of these input documents, forms a query using these terms,
> executes the query and returns the results. The user controls the
> input documents, how the terms should be selected and how the query is
> formed.

Comment: thanks @rabbitbr , needed to start maintaining the elastic id for each index item on my rdbms for this, but it works like a charm!